# Abort a program after a certain time

Tags: linux, time, abort

I'm trying to develop a test case for a program, and would like to fail the test case if it runs over 4 seconds.
How can this be done on linux? (I'm using Ubuntu)

I know I can time the execution and fail it time > 4, but that's just a bad approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Well I don't like either of the answers, isn't there some way to do it with a timeout?

Comment: You've got to set a limit somewhere. A worse solution would be an infinite loop checking constantly; that would rise CPU usage, and possibly affecting the test case duration. Updated my answer again, you can now choose an interval (currently set to 0.5 seconds), and if your testcase finishes immediately, there is no delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(shell script solution)
Runs your testcase in background, get the PId of it, and checks after 4 seconds if the process is still running.

```
wait_seconds=4
interval_seconds=0.5
run_your_test_case &
pid=$!
max=`expr "$wait_seconds / $interval_seconds"`
for (( I=0; I<$max; I++ ));do
    if kill -0 $pid >/dev/null;then
       echo 'test failed'
    else
       echo 'test ok'
       break
    fi
    sleep $interval_seconds
done
```

Comment: Works great! Changed  >/dev/null to 2>/dev/null
However, now the test takes a *minimum* of 4 seconds

Comment: Updated, it now takes 1, 2, 3 or 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:

```
  1 ./slowprogram.sh >/dev/null &
  2 pid=$!
  3 exitbreak=0
  4 for c in {0..4}; do
  5         sleep 1
  6         kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null
  7         if [ $? -ne 0 ] ;then
  8             exitbreak=1
  9             break
 10         fi
 11 done
 12 if  [ $exitbreak == 1 ]; then
 13         echo '[ OK ]'
 14 else
 15         echo '[FAIL]'
 16         kill -9 $pid 2>/dev/null 
 17 fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like `<command> & sleep 5 && kill ${!}`